# AutoIt simulate new script line

Tags: function, loops, inline, autoit

I need some way to loop in a single line.

Is there a way to simulate new lines in AutoIt? Because if I try

```
While 1 MsgBox (0,1,2) Wend
```

It will not work. So I was wondering if there is a way to simulate a new line, something like

```
While 1 - MsgBox (0,1,2) - Wend
```

Or some function to do this. I also already tried to make this:

```
Func repeat($func, $limit)
    $i = 0
    While $i <= $limit
            Execute($func)
            $i = $i + 1
    WEnd
EndFunc
```

But it only executes `Execute($func)` once, even if I change `While $i <= $limit` for `While 1`.

---

I have tried

```
Execute("While $i <= 5" & @LF & "MsgBox(0, 1, 24)" & @LF & "$i = $i + 1" & @LF & "WEnd")
```

too, it doesn't work even if I change `@LF` for `@CRLF`, `@CR`, `Chr(13)`, `\n`, `\r`...

---

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

Nope.  AutoIt can only handle one statement per line.  If you want to do any loops, you're going to have to space it out on multiple lines.

It was also asked on AutoIt's message board here if you wish to see for yourself: http://www.autoitscript.com/forum/topic/141165-loops-in-a-single-line/

Answer (score 0):

AutoIt wasn't built to read multiple commands on a single line. There is no separator character used to parse multiple commands on a single line. The devs of AutoIt also don't plan on using this type of syntax either, as it breaks away from its current syntax implementation.